# Assigning values for write_ascii_values in pyvisa for serial port

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, pyvisa

I want to control my Keithley 6485 Picoammeter externally by connecting it via RS232toUSB to my Linux PC (CentOS 6.9) and writing a code in python (version 2.7.13) with pyvisa:

```css
#! /usr/local/bin/python2.7

import sys
import visa
from visa import constants

rm = visa.ResourceManager('/usr/local/vxipnp/linux/lib64/libvisa.so')
#open serial connection and set baud to 9600, 8 data bits, CR termination, one stop bit, none parity, no flow control
amm = rm.open_resource('ASRL2::INSTR', baud_rate = 9600, data_bits = 8, write_termination= '\r', read_termination = '\r')
constants.VI_ASRL_STOP_ONE     
constants.VI_ASRL_PAR_NONE
constants.VI_ASRL_FLOW_NONE                  
amm.write("*RST")                       # Return 6485 to RST default
amm.write("SYS:ERR:ALL?")               # Return error message 
amm.write("TRIG:DEL 0")                 # Set trigger delay to zero seconds
amm.write("TRIG:COUNT 2500")            # Set trigger count to 2500
amm.write("SENS:CURR:RANG:AUTO OFF")    # Turn auto range off
amm.write("SENS:CURR:NPLC .01")         # Set integration rate to NPLC 0.01
amm.write("SENS:CURR:RANG 2e-7")        # Use 200 nA range 
amm.write("SYST:ZCH OFF")               # Turn zero check off
amm.write("SYST:AZER:STAT OFF")         # Turn auto zero off
amm.write("DISP:ENAB OFF")              # Turn Display off
amm.write("*CLS")                       # Clear status model
amm.write("TRAC:POIN 2500")             # Set buffer size to 2500
amm.write("TRAC:CLE")                   # Clear buffer
amm.write("TRAC:FEED:CONT NEXT")        # Set storage control to start on next reading
amm.write("STAT:MEAS:ENAB 512")         # Enable buffer full measurement event
amm.write("*SRE 1")                     # Enable SRQ on buffer full measurement event
amm.write("*OPC?")                      # operation complete query (synchronize completion of commands)    
amm.write("INIT")                       # start taking and storing readings wait for GPIB SRQ line to go true
amm.write("DISP:ENAB ON")               # Turn display on
print(amm.query_ascii_values("TRAC:DATA?")) # Request data from buffer
```

The problem when I run this script I just get "1" as the print output, although it should be returned in ASCII like this: Reading, Timestamp, Status and the error message after amm.write("*RST"): -113 undefined header. So I think the messages and not transferred correctly.

I know over the RS-232 interface, only the ASCII format is allowed. But when I follow the example in the [pyvisa instruction](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rvalues.html#reading-ascii-values) with write_ascii_values(text, values) and assigning it a list, I only get an error message from the device -100 Command error.

Can somebody please tell me how to set the variables in write_ascii_values correctly or what I am doing wrong? Are my settings for the serial device wrong? Sometimes when I execute 2 times I get the error "VI_ERROR_ASRL_FRAMING (-1073807253): A framing error occurred during transfer ." too. I just do not know what to do.

Thank you!

Regards,
Roland

Answer (score 1):

SCPI has several protocol rules. Hopefully I can guide you through the "query" rule.

If you ask an instrument a query, you must read the result in the buffer:

```
amm.write("*RST")                       # Return 6485 to RST default 
amm.write("SYS:ERR:ALL?")               # Return error message  
amm.write("TRIG:DEL 0")                 # Set trigger delay to zero seconds
```

Once you have sent "SYS:ERR:ALL?" the instrument is expecting you to read the result. Turn it from a write command to a query otherwise the following commands will error and not perform as expected:

```
amm.write("*RST")                               # Return 6485 to RST default 
print(amm.query_ascii_values("SYS:ERR:ALL?"))   # Return error message  
amm.write("TRIG:DEL 0")                         # Set trigger delay to zero seconds
```

This is the same for the operation complete command:

```
print(amm.query_ascii_values("*OPC?"))          # operation complete query (synchronize completion of commands)
```

*OPC? will return a '1' when the previous command has finished.